# Disambiguating org-refile in case of duplicate buffer names?

Tags: org-mode, helm

I have several project directories with the same structure. As a result, I am often annoyed when I have to refile (`C-c C-w`) some sections because several buffers have the same names.

For instance, the list of targets Emacs shows me is something like:

> ```
> workInProgess.org/Tasks
> workInProgess.org/Tasks
> ...
> ```

**How can I configure Emacs to disambiguate these refile targets name?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**A first solution** solution is to define

```
(setq org-refile-use-outline-path 'full-file-path)
```

you will get full file paths, however, this can be quite long:

> ```
> /home/MyHome/...long_path_here.../MyProjectA/workInProgess.org/Tasks
> /home/MyHome/...long_path_here.../MyProjectB/workInProgess.org/Tasks
> ...
> ```

and thus reduce readability.

**A second solution, I prefer**, is to use:

```
(setq org-refile-use-outline-path 'buffer-name)
```

in conjunction with the [uniquify package](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/uniquify).

Once configured with:

```
(require 'uniquify)
(setq uniquify-buffer-name-style 'post-forward-angle-brackets)
```

you will get (when refiling):

> ```
> workInProgess.org<MyProjectA>/Tasks
> workInProgess.org<MyProjectB>/Tasks
> ...
> ```

which it the best of two worlds: short but unambiguous refile targets.

---

**Note:** to make it works with helm (`M-x helm-mode`) you must let Org generates all of the possible completions and present them at once thanks to:

```
(setq org-outline-path-complete-in-steps nil)
```